# Rails 5.2 partial counter: "undefined local variable or method" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Per the information box on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials:

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called
>   by the collection, named after the title of the partial followed by
>   _counter. For example, when rendering a collection @products the partial **_product.html.erb** can access the variable **product_counter**
>   which indexes the number of times it has been rendered within the
>   enclosing view.

However, I am getting and error when referencing the counter in my partial. Here is the parent view:

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment_template', collection: @post.comments, as: :c %>
```

Here is the relevant part of **_comment_template.html.erb**:

```
<%= comment_template_counter %>
```

And here is the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `comment_template_counter' for #<#<Class: [etc.]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've renamed my partial from "_comment_template.html.erb" to "_comment.html.erb" (and updated the various references) but the error persists.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the documentation is incorrect. As pointed out by **pedroadame** at https://coderwall.com/p/t0no0g/render-partial-with-collection-has-hidden-index, when using the **:as** option, I need to use the name of the *variable* rather than the name of the *partial*.

Furthermore, if elsewhere in my app I am only rendering the partial once instead of as a collection, I need to sidestep the (same) error message by checking whether the counter is defined.

So in my partial, this now works:

```
<%= c_counter if defined? c_counter %>
```